# Vector pointer, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Everything works fine except the last line of code. I expect that (*v)[0] is same as aVector[0] that is 0.0903987. But that line can't be compiled and the execution was stop working... any idea why?

```
vector<float>* generateNums(int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    RandomNum randomNum(n, seed1, seed2, seed3);
    vector<float> *v = randomNum.getPointer();
    return v;
}


int main()
{
    vector<float> *v = generateNums(ROW_SIZE*COL_SIZE); 

    cout << "v is " << v << endl;
    cout << "(*v)[0] is " << (*v)[0] << endl;   <---this line doesn't work 
}
```

Output:

```
aVector[0] is 0.0903987
&aVector is 0x22fec0
v is 0x22fec0
```

But if I get rid of the function, it compiles and get the value of (*v)[0].

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    RandomNum randomNum(ROW_SIZE*COL_SIZE, seed1, seed2, seed3);
    vector<float> *v = randomNum.getPointer();
    cout << "v is " << v << endl;
    cout << "(*v)[0] is " << (*v)[0] << endl;
}
```

output:

```
aVector[0] is 0.408055
&aVector is 0x22fef0
v is 0x22fef0
(*v)[0] is 0.408055
```

Comment: If there's output that means it compiled, do you mean to say the program crashes at that point? You'll need to show at least what `randomNum.getPointer();` does.

Comment: What does randomNum.getPointer(); do?

Comment: at that point, a pop up window saying "program.exe has stopped working"...  does it indicate the program crashes?

Comment: @Dominic  randomNum.getPointer() returns the pointer (reference) of the vector<float>.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MLAC, if getPointer doesn't new something, then that's probably returning a pointer that is going to dangle when randomNum goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: Only call `srand` once.

Comment: maybe `return 0;` from `main`?

Comment: post the code of `randomNum.getPointer()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch:

```
RandomNum randomNum(n, seed1, seed2, seed3);
vector<float> *v = randomNum.getPointer();
```

the above call returns a pointer to a member of `randomNum`. When the function returns, `randomNum` gets destructed. Hence, the returned value is a dangling pointer.

**One solution**

Change the function to return a vector instead of a pointer to a vector.

```
vector<float> generateNums(int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    RandomNum randomNum(n, seed1, seed2, seed3);
    vector<float> v = *(randomNum.getPointer());
    return v;
}
```

and then, change the usage:

```
vector<float> v = generateNums(ROW_SIZE*COL_SIZE); 
cout << "v[0] is " << v[0] << endl;
```

Comment: yours is passing by value, isn't it? It copies the vector. But I tried to pass it by reference.

Comment: @MLAC, yes. Passing by reference is OK as long the referenced object continues to be valid when the reference is used. In your case, the referenced object is destroyed before the reference is used. That causes a dangling pointer problem.

Answer (score -1):

At `generateNums` function you define a **local variable** named `randomNum`. After calling `randomNum` it will be destroyed and `v` will refer to a destroyed variable that you can't access.